# VSTO Word Application events for new Word documents, windows or instances

Tags: events, ms-word, vsto

In a VSTO addin for Word 16 (32) on a Windows 10, I keep track of each document for Ribbon purposes.

I am using the VSTO Designer's Application object.  In the designer it looks like this;

```
Friend WithEvents Application As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
```

Then in ThisAddinn I have the standard code for a WithEvents object.

```
 Private Sub Application_NewDocument(Doc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document) Handles Application.NewDocument

 End Sub
```

In ThisAddin I also handle Application.DocumentOpen

After the first instance of Word is open if a user right clicks on the Word icon in the task bar and chooses Word then a new Word document is created, however the above 2 events do not fire.

I also wanted to point out that opening a document from the Word interface or clicking on a word.docx file and opening it all work.  It is only when you open a new instance of work by right clicking on the word icon in the task bar.

What event do I need?

I do see that Application.WindowActivate fires.  Do I need to use this?

Comment: Where and when do you subscribe to the events in the code?

Comment: Question updated.  I am using the VSTO designer's application withevents object.

Comment: At startup, you can check whether any document is opened and simulate the DocumentOpen event fired. It seems that events can be fired before you subscribe to them.

Comment: At start up I do check for open documents.  The problem is that when you start a second word document from the task bar startup does not fire either.

Answer (score 0):

The [Application.NewDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Word.Application.NewDocument(even)) event is fired when a new document is created. If you are working with a document embedded within another document, this event will not occur. You may try to use the following VBA macro to make sure events are fired:

```
Public WithEvents appWord as Word.Application 

Private Sub appWord_NewDocument(ByVal Doc As Document) 
 Dim intResponse As Integer 
 Dim strName As String 
 Dim docLoop As Document 

 intResponse = MsgBox("Save all other documents?", vbYesNo) 

 If intResponse = vbYes Then 
 strName = ActiveDocument.Name 
 For Each docLoop In Documents 
 With docLoop 
 If .Name <> strName Then 
 .Save 
 End If 
 End With 
 Next docLoop 
 End If 
End Sub
```

The [Application.DocumentOpen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.documentopen) event is fired when a document is opened.

```
Public WithEvents appWord as Word.Application 

Private Sub appWord_DocumentOpen(ByVal Doc As Document) 
 Dim intResponse As Integer 
 Dim strName As String 
 Dim docLoop As Document 

 intResponse = MsgBox("Save all other documents?", vbYesNo) 

 If intResponse = vbYes Then 
 strName = ActiveDocument.Name 
 For Each docLoop In Documents 
 With docLoop 
 If .Name <> strName Then 
 .Save 
 End If 
 End With 
 Next docLoop 
 End If 
End Sub
```

At startup, you can check whether any document is opened and simulate the `DocumentOpen` event fired. It seems that events can be fired before you subscribe to them.